# Handling 'Enter' Key on UWP application

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have written a keyevent handler to intercept the keystrokes and do actions based on the key. I have an action for Enter key. But when I have the keyboard focus on an element and I press Enter, the app is performing a click on the element and doing the action I defined. How do I stop the app from clicking the selection when Enter is clicked?

Edit: To clarify, I want the app to stop opening selected items with Enter as I have set Enter to a different action.

Comment: Do you mean that disable select state after enter clicked?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I don't want Enter to be the selector. I when I press enter, I don't want the app to open the selected item.

Comment: @AmlNryn, I have replied below.

Answer (score 0):

> Handling 'Enter' Key on UWP application

If you want to prevent <kbd>Enter</kbd> from triggering the Click event, you could override [`OnProcessKeyboardAccelerators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.onprocesskeyboardaccelerators) method of Button like the following.

```
private void MyControl_ProcessKeyboardAccelerators(UIElement sender, ProcessKeyboardAcceleratorEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I went another way. app will set focus to the main page when the key event was handled. I couldn't handle the Enter but since I changed the focus it didn't open the selected item.
Thanks for your answer, I will try it out as well.

Comment: Do you solve your issue, Any updates for this thread?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the earlier comment, I have solved the issue by checking whether the key was handled and remove the focus from the element if it was handled. I couldn't use your solution since I was using in Enter to select in some other pages which meant i had to implement the event handler on multiple pages. On the one i tried it worked.

Comment: Cool. if you have solved your issue, you could post it as answer and mark yourself. Certainly, I could also update my answer with your solution comment if you want.